# iOS - Posting image and text to FB User's wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating iOS app using latest Facebook framework 3.1 
I've seen lots of content regarding posting image and text to facebook user's wall. I'm using the following code.

```
    NSDictionary* dict = @{
        @"link" : @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios",
        @"picture" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"],
        @"message":@"Your temp message here",
        @"name" : @"MyApp",
        @"caption" : @"TestPost",
        @"description" : @"Integrating Facebook in ios"
    };
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:dict HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSString *alertText;
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"error: domain = %@, code = %d", error.domain, error.code]);
        alertText = @"Failed to post to Facebook, try again";
    } else
    {
        alertText = @"Posted successfully to Facebook";
    }

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Result" message:alertText delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}];
```

If I'm providing the picture as "URL" its posting fine. Else its throwing error. I want to post an image that is within the application bundle. Can some on tell me where I'm coding wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post photo on user's wall using Facebook iOS SDK](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk)

Comment: Look at this tutorial - Its for Facebook SDK 3.0 but will get you exactly what you are looking for - http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

Comment: @Igy: Using the URL you suggested, I'm able to post photo only. I want to post photo, message, name and URL as well.

Comment: So you want to make a feed post, not a photo post? you have the correct code for that with the exception of trying to upload the photo bytes, which is not supported - look at the documentation again, the `picture` parameter is supposed to be a URL

Comment: @Igy But I have the images within the app. When I use @"me/photos", its just posting image and message and not taking other parameters.

Comment: Yes, you're trying to take features from two different APIs - uploading a status update to the `feed` connection requires a photo URL and you can specify description, title, action links, etc. 
Uploading a photo allows you only to set the photo and a description/caption

Comment: @Igy The requirement is something like posting image of person, title, short description and webpage related to that person.

Comment: So you want to post either to the feed connection (which needs a photo URL) or via an Open Graph action with a user generated photo attached - the photos API does not support your use case

Comment: Which API can I use for my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature.jpg"]; 

NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"My First message" forKey:@"message"];    
[params setObject:image forKey:@"picture"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:dict HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSString *alertText;
    if (error)
    {
 NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"error: domain = %@, code = %d", error.domain, error.code]);
    alertText = @"Failed to post to Facebook, try again";
} else
{
    alertText = @"Posted successfully to Facebook";
}

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Result" message:alertText delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}];
```

Comment: This is the Best way for Upload Image with Text and Link also.
 Its working on android and iOS both.